# Acking activemq using python and stomp

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I have an activemq set up with a ton of api calls to Zendesk. I need to retrieve those calls and then remove them from the queue entirely. conn.ack doesn't seem to be working!

I'm using python3 and the most recent version of stomp. I used this to make the initial connection script: https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/wiki/Simple-Example

https://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html
In this doc, it looks like you have to label the "id" tag of the .subscribe method. You call conn.ack with that id, but you also add the message id as an argument. I found out that the headers of the message are retrieved with the listener function. I printed those out and they look like this:

ID:[my workstation id].local-49557-1560302581785-5:58:-1:1:61592

I tried regex'ing out the whole string after ID:, and then I tried regexing out just the number on the very end of the string (it looks like possibly a unique number), but when I do conn.ack (matchObj.group(1), 4), the queue count doesn't change and I get no feedback as to why it doesn't.

The connection works absolutely fine so far-- I just can't send those acks.

```
import stomp
import time
import re

class SampleListener(object):
    def on_message(self, headers, msg):
      regex = r"ID:.*1:1:(.*)"
      print(msg)
      print(headers['message-id'])

      matchObj = re.match ( regex, headers['message-id'], re.M|re.I)
      print (matchObj.group(1))

      conn.ack (matchObj.group(1), 4)

conn = stomp.Connection10()

conn.set_listener('SampleListener', SampleListener())

conn.start()

conn.connect()

conn.subscribe('zendeskqueue', id=4, ack='client')

time.sleep(1) # secs

conn.disconnect()
```

The code above has no error, it just exists without output.

Comment: You need to do some debugging and collect some logs, client and broker, otherwise it is quite hard to say what is happening

Comment: Any clue how to get more verbosity than what I currently have? Nothing comes out of the above

Answer (score 1):

Acknowledging messages with stomp.py and ActiveMQ works using ack id `headers['ack']`.

And you can get more verbose output by implementing `on_error` on your listener, and enabling debug logging.

With both, your code will look like that:

```
import stomp
import time
import logging

class SampleListener(object):
  def on_message(self, headers, msg):
    conn.ack(headers['ack'])

  def on_error(self, headers, body):
    print("An error occurred: headers=" + str(headers) + " ; body=" + str(body))


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('stomp').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

conn = stomp.Connection12()

conn.set_listener('SampleListener', SampleListener())

conn.start()

conn.connect()

conn.subscribe('zendeskqueue', id=4, ack='client')

time.sleep(1) # secs

conn.disconnect()
```

Comment: Note that I used Stomp 1.2 but at the look of ActiveMQ code, it should work as well with 1.0.

Comment: KeyError: 'ack' ... headers['ack'] is not a defined field, do you mean headers['message-id']?